# Separate divs into different parents

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to split child elements into different divs if their total width is greater than the width of the parent element

I need to do this [design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVH7v.png)
So I decided to separate the buttons into different rows and these rows add :before and :after elements, because they also have a hover effect.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="parent">
    <a href="#" class="child">Manufacturing & IOT</a>
    <a href="#" class="child">Software</a>
    <a href="#" class="child">High Tech</a>
    <a href="#" class="child">Media + Entertainment</a>
    <a href="#" class="child">Revenue Management</a>
    <a href="#" class="child">Recurring Billing</a>
    <a href="#" class="child">Recurring Payments</a>
    <a href="#" class="child">Reduce Time-to-Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="child">sage-Based Pricing</a>
    <a href="#" class="child">sage-Based Pricing</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 708px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.parent {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 708px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.parent::before, .parent::after {
    content: '';
    width: 100vw;
    height: 48px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 100px 0px rgba(108, 123, 170, 0.24);
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -21;
}
.parent::before {
    right: calc(100% + 24px);
}
.parent::after {
    left: calc(100% + 24px);
}
.child {
    text-align: center;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: white;
    color: green;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-radius: 40px;
    padding: 13px 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 48px;
    transition: color 0.5s ease, background-color 0.5s ease;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 100px 0px rgba(108, 123, 170, 0.24);
    position: relative;

.child:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
}
```

}

```js
const btnsWrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const containerWidth = btnsWrapper.offsetWidth;

const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
const widthArr = [];

btns.forEach((btn) => {
  widthArr.push(btn.offsetWidth);
  let sum = widthArr.reduce((accumulator, value) => {
    return accumulator + value;
  }, 0);

  if (sum > containerWidth) {
    const newRow = document.createElement('div');
    newRow.classList.add('parent');

    btnsWrapper.appendChild(newRow);

    newRow.appendChild(btn);
  }
});
```

And the result should be something like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
        <a href="#" class="child">Manufacturing & IOT</a>
        <a href="#" class="child">Software</a>
        <a href="#" class="child">High Tech</a>
        <a href="#" class="child">Media + Entertainment</a>
    <div class="parent">
        <a href="#" class="child">Revenue Management</a>
        <a href="#" class="child">Recurring Billing</a>
        <a href="#" class="child">Recurring Payments</a>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
        <a href="#" class="child">Reduce Time-to-Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="child">Usage-Based Pricing</a>
        <a href="#" class="child">Usage-Based Pricing</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what doesn't work? Any errors? Please read [ask] about creating a good question.

Comment: "width" in this context involves additional information including any applied CSS here.  We need more details to resolve this including what sizes the parent, the child elements and what constrains that parents width etc.  I made a snippet of the code but it currently lacks any CSS or other width defining capability at all.  Your sample HTML looks nothing remotely like the picture.

Answer (score 1):

To make any overflowing element get sent to the next parent, depending on the width of the wrapper :

```js
const btnsWrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const containerWidth = btnsWrapper.offsetWidth;

const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
const widthArr = [];

btns.forEach((btn) => {
    widthArr.push({
        width: btn.offsetWidth,
        element: btn
    });
});

let sum = widthArr.reduce((accumulator, value) => {
    let current_sum = accumulator + value.width;
    // Mark overflowing elements
    if(current_sum > containerWidth) {
        value.to_move = true;
    }
    return current_sum;
}, 0);

// Prepare the next parent if needed
if(sum > containerWidth) {
    const newRow = document.createElement('div');
    newRow.classList.add('parent');
    btnsWrapper.appendChild(newRow);

    // Move all elements that have been marked
    widthArr.filter((value) => value.to_move).forEach(value=> {
        value.btn.remove();
        newRow.appendChild(value.btn);
    });
}
```

Depending on your needs, you may want to repeat this operation until the sum of the last `parent` is lower than containerWidth, but the initial variables that you set will not do the trick, you need to only get the ones from the last parent.

---

### If you are just trying to make elements go to the next line when overflowing. :

You don't need javascript for that : you could instead use flexbox's `flex-wrap: wrap` property in the CSS.

```css
/* remove the "parent" div and put your children inside the wrapper directly */
.wrapper {
    /* enable flexbox on this element */
    display: flex; 

    /* makes elements go horizontally (this is by default, but you can also use "column") */
    flex-direction: row; 

    /* make overflowing elements wrap vertically */
    flex-wrap: wrap; 

    /* you need the container to have some kind of width, else it will extend */
    width: 150px; 
}
```

Read more about flexbox : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: No, each new row should be into a new parent element.

Comment: Then, as is, all your children will have the same width. It is not clear what you want to do with their widths individually, or whether you want to do something depending on the total width of the wrapper.

Comment: @Andrew Why? Sounds like an XY problem. Maybe you could update your question with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to split child elements into different divs if their total width is greater than the width of the parent element

Comment: I will update my answer

Comment: @Andrew just repeating the same thing over and over, is not an explanation as to _why_ you would need this.

Comment: Answer updated to do just what you described.